# Update user profile on Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with updating the user profile. In my case I am going to update two fields of the user (location and availability). The data type of them is in boolean. Please help with how to update the user profile. My way is following:

```
private void updateProfile() {
    final Boolean isAvailable = swIsAvailable.isChecked();
    final Integer spinnerIndex = spLocation.getSelectedItemPosition();
    final Boolean location;


    if(spinnerIndex == 0){
        location = false;
    }else {
        location =true;
    }

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    User updateUser = new User();

    updateUser.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    updateUser.where = location;
    
    user.updateProfile(updateUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "User Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

My user class is:

```
public class User {
    public String fullName, phoneNumber, carName, email, uriImage;
    public Boolean isAvailable, where;

    public User(){

    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public User(String fullName, String phoneNumber, String carName, String email, Boolean isAvailable, Boolean where, String uriImage){
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.carName = carName;
        this.email = email;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
        this.where = where;
        this.uriImage = uriImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? For example: if you step through this code in a debugger line by line, which exact line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: On this line " user.updateProfile(updateUser).addOnCompleteListener" updateUser asking to add add "UserProfileChangeRequest" I do not have no idea what to do:(

Comment: I recommend following the documentation found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile. It shows you how to build a `UserProfileChangeRequest`

Comment: I tried to follow this article but did not understand well. Can you please explain it more bit? I would appreciate your help

Comment: I wrote an answer below. But if something isn't clear, you'll have to be a bit more explicit about what wasn't clear about it. Without knowing exactly what is confusing for you, it's unlikely we'll do a better job explaining something than the official documentation does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following method to your User class:

```
public class User {
    // ... your class props and constructors here

    // add this method
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        if(fullName != null)
            result.put("fullName", fullName);
        if(phoneNumber != null)
            result.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        if(carName != null)
            result.put("carName", carName);
        if(email != null)
            result.put("email", email);
        if(isAvailable != null)
            result.put("isAvailable", isAvailable);
        if(where != null)
            result.put("where", where);
        if(uriImage != null)
            result.put("uriImage", uriImage);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And update any prop you want like so:

```
User u = new User();

u.isAvailable = false; // new values go here
u.where = true; // new values go here

Map<String, Object> newUserValues = u.toMap();

reference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(newUserValues).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // successfully updated
        
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        // failed to update
        // handle error here
    }
});
```

Where `reference` is `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");`
and `user` is `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`

Comment: Wow, you are my hero, i have been trying to find solution for a week. you did it great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the Firebase documentation on [updating a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) shows, you need to build a `UserProfileChangeRequest`. From the docs:

> ```
> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
>
> UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
>        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
>        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
>        .build();
>
> user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
>        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>            @Override
>            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
>                }
>            }
>        });
> ```

Comment: Well, in my case, what should i write inside setDisplayName

Comment: What other property of Firebase's user profile are you looking to update?

Comment: I am going to update child of User collection items (where, and isAvailable)

Comment: Those are not properties that can be stored in the Firebase Authentication profile of a user, so you can't pass them into the call to `user.updateProfile`.

Comment: no update, I am trying to find solution but could not:(